# How do I spoof a request host in an rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

We have a small method that some of our other teams use internally. I'm writing tests for it, but I have run in to a small issue:

The method itself checks to ensure the request comes from a specific server (request.host). I have tried stubbing, but I perhaps was stubbing the wrong controllers? I tried the controller I was testing and .any_instance, then I tried controller.any_instance, but neither worked.

I have a hunch that I might be able to spoof it using devise, but so far google has yet to yield much usefulness.

Comment: rather then only allowing requests from a specific server, maybe create a whitelist of servers. Then just add localhost / 127.0.0.1 to the list.

Comment: This would then prevent us from testing the guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel mildly stupid for not trying this first, but:

In a test where I am trying to spoof request.host, the way to set this in your corresponding test is:

*drumroll please...*

```
request.host = dev.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing subdomains, I have a writeup with some code here: http://www.chrisaitchison.com/2013/03/17/testing-subdomains-in-rails/